# Materialize.css autocomplete - how to make list open with minLength = 0

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, materialize

Using Materialize.css autocomplete: I want the list to open upon focusing the textbox, even without entering any char. I tried to set {minLength: 0}:

```
$('#dataset_input').autocomplete({data: res, limit : 20, minLength: 0})
```

but it **doesn't seems to work**.

The reason I suspect is the check for the val(from github):

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
                      key.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 &&
                      key.toLowerCase() !== val) {
                    // Break if past limit
                    if (count >= options.limit) {
                      break;
                    }
```

and the val in this case is length 0.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine with the version v0.98.2 of materializecss.

I just took the sample from the materializecss website and added your code (with sample data for autocomplete).

This is what I did and it worked:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                    <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                    <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#autocomplete-input').autocomplete({data: {"Apple": null,"Microsoft": null,"Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'}, limit : 20, minLength: 0})
    });
</script>
```